# Is there any method to hide the subtitle in android VideoView?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working with VideoView where i have a custom toggle (ON/OFF). Also, i have subtitle files with extension .vtt inside raw folder for all videos. While watching the video, user can toggle ON/OFF. When toggle is "ON" then videoView must start showing subtitles. Similarly, "OFF" will make the subtitles closed/hidden. So far I have been able to show the subtitles using the code mentioned below. But, i didn't find a way to hide the subtitles when i click "OFF".

```
mVideoView.addSubtitleSource(inputStream, MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/vtt", Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));
```

Comment: Please let me know in case you need more information....I have elaborated the requirements...It should be clear now...

Answer (score 0):

Set the source again to null or point it to a blank file.

Comment: Already tried but not working:

mVideoView.addSubtitleSource([Blank_File], MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/vtt",Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));

Comment: It doesn't stop showing subtitles even after loading the blank file....I don't know why..